# SQL Query: to fetch data in range

Tags: mysql

I have a table named as **tbl_bin_ranges** here I need to find that surcharge will be applied on card number or not?

**tbl_bin_ranges**

```
id         low_bin         max_bin        is_surcharge
---------------------------------------------------------
1          545454          545460             1
2          100000          100000             0
3          545             550                0
```

Here If a customer passed card number as **5454555454555454** then it should return row 1 with value since the initial 6 digits come in the range of row 1.

I had to apply multiple where or to resolve this. So I am wondering that is it a good option to use multiple **where or** if the length of the table increase for any other condition.

Sample working query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `tbl_card_bin_range`
WHERE
    1 = 1 AND(
        (
            low_bin <= '545' AND max_bin >= '545'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '5454' AND max_bin >= '5454'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '54545' AND max_bin >= '54545'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '545455' AND max_bin >= '545455'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '5454555' AND max_bin >= '5454555'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '54545554' AND max_bin >= '54545554'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '545455545' AND max_bin >= '545455545'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '5454555454' AND max_bin >= '5454555454'
        ) OR(
            low_bin <= '54545554545' AND max_bin >= '54545554545'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    CHAR_LENGTH( low_bin ) DESC, CHAR_LENGTH( max_bin )
DESC
```

Comment: Wouldn't row 3 match the criteria too?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Mohit Gupta 'Wouldn't row 3 match the criteria too?' - indeed it does using your code. Surely there is some rule which defines the minimum characters that should be used for given user input?

Comment: Yes, to get the least match data I updated the order by **CHAR_LENGTH( low_bin ) DESC, CHAR_LENGTH( max_bin )** and will pick it by 0 index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_card_bin_range
WHERE LEFT(@passed_card_number, LENGTH(low_bin)) BETWEEN low_bin AND max_bin
ORDER BY LENGTH(low_bin) DESC LIMIT 1
```

How it works?

Firstly, we determine the length of the prefixes in current row using `LENGTH(low_bin)`. **Important!** The lengths of both columns values (`low_bin` and `max_bin`) in a row must be the same. So according CHECK constraint must be defined in the table's structure.

Then we extract the prefix of the same length from the value to be checked using LEFT() function, and check (using BETWEEN operator) does the prefix matches the range in a row.

And the last step - we order by the length and take one output row where the prefix length is maximal (i.e. the range is the narrowest).

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, how it will work?

Comment: @MohitGupta Some explanations added.